# Reduction of SUBSET-SUM to SET-PARTITION

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, partitions

There is a similar question that has been asked, but my question addresses particular detail of an answer.

I am trying to reduce SUBSET-SUM to SET-PARTITION. I found the following description:

SUBSET-SUM is defined as follows: Given a set `X` of integers and a target number `t`, find a subset `Y` from `X` such that the members of `Y` add up to exactly `t`. Let `s` be the sum of members of `X`. Feed `X' = X U {s - 2t}` into SET-PARTITION. Accept if and only if SET-PARTITION accepts.

What does "`X' = X U {s - 2t}`" (union?) and "Feed `X' = X U {s - 2t}` into SET-PARTITION" mean? How does this prove that SUBSET-SUM can be reduced to SET-PARTITION?

Comment: Yup, that means union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing here is adding a new element to your original set 'X'. The value for this new element is (s - 2t). Hence, X' now contains one extra element as compared to X.

The SET-PARTITION would "accept" if the provided set can be partitioned into two subsets with equal sum. We were already able to pick out a subset 'Y', from the set X, the sum of whose elements was 't'. If we include the extra element (s-2t) in this subset Y, the sum of its elements would now become ( t + s - 2*t ) = (s-t). This is also the sum of the elements which are remaining in the set (X - Y). Hence, X' can be divided into two subsets each of whose sum is (s-t).

Comment: I am confused. By 'S' you mean 'Y' right?

Comment: Yes, I meant Y, I have updated my comment.

Comment: Thanks! Took me a while to understand your answer. Whoever discovered this reduction must be a genius!